# General floating-point maths query

Tags: javascript, math, floating-point-precision

Okay so I get that some numbers can't be represented properly in binary just like 1/3 can't be fully represented in decimal.

So how come when I console.log(0.3) it returns 0.3
but when I console.log(0.1 + 0.2) it returns the 0.30000000000000004

How come it is accounting for the error (if it even is) when simply outputting 0.3 but doesn't when the addition occurs?

Comment: Removed [python] tag because this is specific to JavaScript's display of numbers.

Comment: @Wooble Actually Python exhibits the same behavior, even with a somewhat-recent change that hides such small errors in the display of many floats.

Comment: Well, `repr` does. `str` does not.

Comment: To see on your own what you've been answered, try to force the system to represent the numbers with higher precision than the default one. E.g, try (in Python) `{:.20f}".format(0.1)`

Comment: @Wooble In recent versions both do because both use the new algorithm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose we approximate 1/3 and 2/3 in decimal.

```
1/3 = 0.333
2/3 = 0.667
```

and we add 1/3+1/3:

```
1/3+1/3 = 0.333 + 0.333 = 0.666
```

We didn't get our approximation of 2/3. Rounding 1/3 to something we can represent in decimal didn't produce a number equal to half of what we got when we rounded 2/3.

The same thing happens in binary. We round 0.1 and 0.2 to numbers we can represent in binary, but the sum of the approximations is slightly different from what we get if we approximate 0.3. We get something a bit higher, and the result is displayed as `0.30000000000000004`.

Comment: really well explained drawing on an easily recognisable parallel

Answer (score 4):

The inaccuracies in the internal representations of `0.1` and `0.2` are small enough that the Javascript printer ignores them when it's printing these numbers. But when you add them together the inaccuracies accumulate, and this is enough to show up when the result is printed.

Answer (score 2):

The way Java prints floating-point numbers is a significant part of the behavior you are seeing: By default, Java does not print the exact value of a floating-point number. It prints just enough digits to precisely identify the `double` that is being printed.

Thus, if you set `x` to `.3`, `x` is actually set to 0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875. When Java prints this, it prints only “.3”, because converting “.3” to `double` yields the value of `x`, 0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875.

When you use `.1` and `.2`, these are actually the values 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625 and 0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125. When you add them (in `double` format), the result is 0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125.

When you print this value, Java prints “0.30000000000000004” because it needs to show all those digits in order to produce a numeral that, when converted back to `double`, will produce 0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125.

---

Here is [the documentation for how `double` values are printed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html). It says:

> How many digits must be printed for the fractional part…? There must be at least one digit to represent the fractional part, and beyond that as many, but only as many, more digits as are needed to uniquely distinguish the argument value from adjacent values of type `double`.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, in base 10 you can't accurately describe the fraction 1/3.  Similarly, in base 2, you can't accurately describe certain other fractions.  So, when the computer adds 0.1 and 0.2, it's actually adding something like 0.10000000001 and 0.20000000003.

Comment: But this doesn't explain why `console.log(0.1)` shows `0.1` rather than `0.10000000001`

Comment: When you just want to send something to console.log, there isn't any arithmetic involved.  When you add two floating point numbers, that's where the inaccuracies come into play.

Comment: What about the inaccuracy produced when it parses `0.1` into a float, whose internal value is something like 0.1000000001`.

Comment: @danmullen: There is arithmetic involved in sending something to console.log. The value must be formatted, including conversion from `double` to a decimal numeral. This involves quite a lot of arithmetic. And there are inaccuracies: When the `double` value 0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875 is printed, “.3” is produced. So the conversion for printing introduces error.

Comment: Accepted, but from your example I would guess that when just printing a number there is possibly some rounding involved.  When you add floating point numbers (or do other arithmetic operations on them) the inaccuracies in how they are represented internally have a cumulative effect.