# Calculate the difference between 2 double numbers

Tags: java, floating-point, floating-accuracy

Why do I get 0.6100000000000001 when I should get 0.61 ? I know the get I know the decimal format to fix it. I just want the explanation for why it happens.

```
public class Mid2009{
    public static void main (String args []){
        double d1 = 1.03;
        double d2 = 0.42;
        double d3 = d1-d2;
        System.out.println(d3);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to the programming world](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: it is one of the glorious things about programming.

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Possible duplicate of may existing questions, like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490511/general-floating-point-maths-query